# Using Mercurial, how can I see what changes have yet to be pushed?

Tags: mercurial

I'm used to git, where you can run gitk and get something like the following:

[image: gitk showing the difference between the local and remote branches]

Here you can see that there are a couple of changes that need pushing to the remote branch. Alternatively, I can use `git log --decorate` and the output would be:

```
b8c2926... (refs/heads/next) Update instructions
6d9f914... Add a first go at generic x compiling
49a6dac... (refs/remotes/github/next) Ignore temp files
```

Is there anything like this with Mercurial?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`hg outgoing` - will show you the changesets that are waiting to be pushed to a remote repository.

`hg incoming` - shows new changesets that are in the remote repository.