# How to see what will be pushed to a Mercurial repo before doing an actual hg push?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I want to push my code to a repo, but before doing so I would like to see what changes the push will send.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Mercurial, how can I see what changes have yet to be pushed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790951/using-mercurial-how-can-i-see-what-changes-have-yet-to-be-pushed)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should display the changesets to be pushed.

```
hg outgoing
```

http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#outgoing

To customize the output, check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3041751/62054